# How to copy directories using sftp with curl command

Tags: curl, ftp, sftp

I am unable to copy the directory from one server to other server using curl with sftp option

If I use sftp alone,-r can be used, but since I need to use sftp along with curl, I am unable to find any option in curl which does that. I have tried the below method

```
    curl -v --insecure "sftp://<ip>/home/user/folder1/--user "user:user" -o "/root/dest_dir/" --ftp-create-dirs
```

and it gives error as
        "Warning: Failed to create the file /root/dest_dir/: Is a directory"

So, is there any option to copy the directory recursively using sftp with curl

Answer (score 2):

No sorry: curl has no option to copy recursively. Not with SFTP, nor with any other protocol.